# Как выполнить событие при определенном условии?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выполнить событие

```
$('.menu').prepend($('.sidebar'));
```

при условии, что размер экрана менее определенного, скажем 800px, размера? И еще такой вопрос: это правильно, что мы переносим один блок в другой при адаптивной верстке именно таким образом, и может оказаться так, что на планшетах или телефонах этот скрипт может просто не сработать? Благодарю!

Comment: да, скрипт может не сработать, потому что у некоторых планшетов ширина уже больше 800px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 800) {
  // твой код
}
```

Но я бы сделал на *css*: просто один блок скрыл и показал его когда ширина экрана меньше 800. Меньше бы *js* привлекал, но это не истина.

Comment: Старайся все, что относится к ответу, в том числе пояснения и дополнения писать в ответе, а не в комментариях к нему.

Comment: Нельзя так делать. Ширина окна может меняться.

Comment: Конкретней почему нельзя...